# How to smoothly move relatively positioned divs filing gaps of other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on an interactive menu with hexagons. When user clicks on one of the hexagons, the other hexagons are supposed to disappear and the one clicked receives the class `selected` and is highlighted on the upper left on the div.

The problem is that the animation is very bad and abrupt, in part because of he way the other divs disappear.

How to smoothly animate the change of position of selected divs in this case?

**EDIT**

Here's a link for the animation, https://codepen.io/sobrancelhas/pen/MbOggV

The first three elements move smoothly.

Comment: Have you looked at css transitions?  They'll be smoother because they're handled by the browser rather than js.

Comment: Can you share you html and css code as well here please.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that all of your hexagons will be disappeared and you do not want this, so add another class to filter divs that must be affected by animation.

```
<div class='hexagon moving'></div>
```

And execute animation on divs with class .moving .

```
$(".moving").not(this).animate(...
```

Comment: @Pete Thanks. Edited.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I'll try and let you know about the progress! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. HTML is needed, so I guessed.
2. CSS is needed, so I guessed.
3. As was already mentioned by @fredomn-m, CSS transitions are a better alternative to JavaScript for simple animation, so I added transitions on the .selected and .open classes.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$('.hexagonTile').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('.circle').toggleClass('open');
  var items = $(this).find('.circle a');

  for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
    items[i].style.left = (50 - 35 * Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2 * (1 / l) * i * Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
    items[i].style.top = (50 + 35 * Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2 * (1 / l) * i * Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
  }

  if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    $(this).removeClass('selected', 1000);
    $(".hexagonTile").not(this).animate({
      'height': 'show',
      'width': 'show',
      'opacity': 'show'
    }, 1000);

  } else {
    $(this).addClass('selected', 1000);
    $(".hexagonTile").not(this).animate({
      'height': 'hide',
      'opacity': 'hide',
      'width': 'hide'
    }, 1000);

  }

});
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
section:nth-of-type(even) {
  left: 29px;
  top: -16px;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #0ff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 7px;
  z-index: 2;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.hexagonTile {
  position: relative;
  width: 55px;
  height: 31.75px;
  background-color: #0f0;
  margin: 15.88px 0;
  border-left: solid 1px #ff0000;
  border-right: solid 1px #ff0000;
}
.hexagonTile:before,
.hexagonTile:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 38.89px;
  height: 38.89px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: inherit;
  left: 7.0546px;
}
.hexagonTile:before {
  top: -19.4454px;
  border-top: solid 1.4142px #ff0000;
  border-right: solid 1.4142px #ff0000;
}
.hexagonTile:after {
  bottom: -19.4454px;
  border-bottom: solid 1.4142px #ff0000;
  border-left: solid 1.4142px #ff0000;
}
.selected {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
.open {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class='flex'>
  <div class='hexagonTile'>
    <div class='circle'><a href='#/'>A</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='hexagonTile'>
    <div class='circle'><a href='#/'>B</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='hexagonTile'>
    <div class='circle'><a href='#/'>C</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='hexagonTile'>
    <div class='circle'><a href='#/'>D</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='hexagonTile'>
    <div class='circle'><a href='#/'>E</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='hexagonTile'>
    <div class='circle'><a href='#/'>F</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='hexagonTile'>
    <div class='circle'><a href='#/'>G</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='hexagonTile'>
    <div class='circle'><a href='#/'>H</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class='flex'>
  <div class='hexagonTile'>
    <div class='circle'><a href='#/'>A</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='hexagonTile'>
    <div class='circle'><a href='#/'>B</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='hexagonTile'>
    <div class='circle'><a href='#/'>C</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='hexagonTile'>
    <div class='circle'><a href='#/'>D</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='hexagonTile'>
    <div class='circle'><a href='#/'>E</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='hexagonTile'>
    <div class='circle'><a href='#/'>F</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='hexagonTile'>
    <div class='circle'><a href='#/'>G</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='hexagonTile'>
    <div class='circle'><a href='#/'>H</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! My goal is a little different from the example you made, although your answer will help me a lot! Thank you so much and I'll try and apply the animation and let you know about the progress!

Comment: You are welcome, if this post resolved you problem click the green ✔ if it was helpful, just upvote ▲, or if it resolved your problem and it was helpful on other levels click ▲and ✔.

Comment: Sorry but it still doesn't seem to have any effect. Here's a link for the sample https://codepen.io/sobrancelhas/pen/MbOggV